# Spring boot one to one with foreign key

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, one-to-one

I am want to store room details and room types in my db. I have created an entity for **Room** as follows.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Room {

        @Id
        private String room_id;

        private Boolean status;

        private Double price;

        private Long type;

        private Long occupancy;

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = false)
        private RoomType roomType;

}
```

I have create a RoomType entity as follows:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class RoomType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String type;
}
```

To save a **Room** Entity in my DB, the following is the request body format need to be given

```
{
  "room_id": "string",
  "status": true,
  "price": 0,
  "roomType": {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "string"
  }
}
```

I want to have the request body as follows

```
{
  "room_id": "string",
  "status": true,
  "price": 0,
  "roomType": 1  # This the roomType foreign key
}
```

I want to have one to one relationship, so when retrieving the **Room** details, I will get the **roomType** values also in the following format.

```
   {
      "room_id": "string",
      "status": true,
      "price": 0,
      "roomType": {
        "id": 0,
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
```

Or Is there any better way to handle this type of problem in spring boot??

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two different concepts in here:

- The inner representation of a `Room` in your service (The classes you use and their relations)
- The outer representation (The one exposed by your API)

If you want those two representation to be the same, you could just serialize/deserialize data using the `Room` class directly (which I assume is what you are currently doing). For example:

```
@Controller
class MyController {
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    public Room createRoom(@RequestBody Room room) {
        // Here room will be automatically deserialized from the request body
        // Do stuff with the received room in here
        // ...
        // Here the returned room will be automatically serialized to 
        // the response body
        return createdRoom;
    }
}
```

However, if you don't want the inner and outer representations to be the same, you can use the DTO pattern (Data Transfer Object). Example in Spring [here](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application).

Now, you would have three different classes, `Room` and it's DTOs:

```
public class RoomRequestDTO {
        private String room_id;
        private Boolean status;
        private Double price;
        private Long type;
        private Long occupancy;
        private Integer roomType; // This is now an Integer

       // Setters and Getters ...
}

public class RoomResponseDTO {
        private String room_id;
        private Boolean status;
        private Double price;
        private Long type;
        private Long occupancy;
        private RoomType roomType;  // This is a RoomType instance

       // Setters and Getters ...
}
```

Now, your controller would receive `RoomRequestDTO`s and send `RoomResponseDTO`s:

```
@Controller
class MyController {
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    public RoomResponseDTO createRoom(@RequestBody RoomRequestDTO roomReqDTO) {
        Room room = ... // Convert from DTO to Room
        // Do stuff with the received room in here
        RoomResponseDTO roomRespDTO = ... // Convert to the DTO
        return roomRespDTO;
    }
}
```

This approach also has the advantage that you can now change the inner representaion of `Room` without afecting the API. This is, you could decide to merge the `Room` and `RoomType` classes in one, without affecting the outer representation.

Note: In the example I have linked, they use the `ModelMapper` library. If you do not desire to introduce that dependecy, you could simple add a contructor and a method to the DTOs as such

```
public RoomResponseDTO(Room room) {
    // Manually asign the desired fields in here
    this.id = room.getId();
    // ...
}
public Room toRoom() {
    Room room = new Room();
    // Manually asing the desired field in here
    room.setId(this.id);
    // ...
    return room;
}
```

However, this approach would make you have to change these methods whenever you want to change the representations of `Room`. The `ModeMapper` library does this for you.